# JQgrid 4.6.0 Form issue

Tags: jqgrid

I have a crazy issue. I had recently upgraded JQGrid to 4.6.0 as I needed Pivot functionalities...

The issue starts after the Jqgrid has loaded. See the sequence of events:

1. I click Add/edit button and everything works perfectly until this time.
2. Now, I close the form(without doing anything) and hit the add button again. The form gets loaded, but the fields are offset. If I had selected the edit button in Step 1, then I get the edit form loaded when add button is clicked and the fields are offset.

I am having this issue for all the JQgrids I have.